# Best way to play Defense of the Ancients (Warcraft 3) on  a Mac?

Tags: macos, dota, warcraft-3-the-frozen-throne, virtualization

I own a Macbook Pro. I want to play a PC game called WarCraft 3 - Defense of the Ancients. I have googled and done some research on how to play DotA on a Mac.

Most of resources I found recommended I buy Warcraft 3 for Mac version (yes, there is warcraft 3 for mac). However, I already own the PC version, and I don't want to waste another $60++ bucks to buy a Mac version (it's an old game as you guys already know).

I also came across some forums suggesting using a virtual machine or using Bootcamp to install Windows and play.

Using bootcamp and installing Windows sounded good for me, but after I did more research, I found that since I don't have experience with using Bootcamp, I might crash or need to reformat my Mac(when partitioning). Apple also recommends doing backups for your Mac when using Bootcamp. I do not want to go through all this troublesome things, thus I will not choose this method.

My last option is to install virtual machine. I used VirtualBox and already installed Windows XP. It runs and works perfectly fine. Now, I am wondering, if I install Warcraft into this virtual machine, and play the game, approximately 5 hours a day, will it crash my Mac?

Okay, to give a summary, following are my questions about running Wacraft 3 on VM Windows XP on MacBook Pro:

1) Will the game lag, the video render okay, etc?
2) Most importantly, will it damage my Mac?

If you have others methods of playing DotA on a Mac other than what I mentioned above, those are welcome too.

Comment: Probably because it's based on a false premise. Warcraft 3 doesn't come in Mac and PC flavours - there's just one product and it works on both Mac OS X and Windows.

Comment: Warcraft III will run on just about any Mac you can find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firs, you should reconsider not buying it. You can have i for 20 USD, available for download at Blizzard site. Furthermore, IIRC you can register you activation key on the new Battle.net site and download the mac version for free.

As for you questions about the VM machine:

- First, it should not damage you mac in any way, that's the point of a virtual machine. It's software computer, using a software hard drive. If it damage your machine, there is something really wrong with the program.
- Warcraft 3 could run on it, but if it require graphic acceleration, don't expect too much. Some VMs have implemented graphics acceleration, but it is mostly experimental. Although, I think it should be OK for Warcraft3.

Comment: VirtualBox does support graphics acceleration, but it isn't enabled by default, there's an extra option when you install the VirtualBox Guest Additions

Answer (score 7):

Just put the Warcraft 3 DVD into your Mac and install it: the DVD has both installers and you don't have to buy another copy.

Answer (score 0):

I used a software called crossover since I couldn't find a MAC version of the game.
I copied the windows installed files into my MAC and used crossover to run the .exe file.
Worked nicely, but I suppose by now you have solved this :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to buy a new game. Warcraft III runs both on Windows and Mac with the same serial number.

You have two options to install the Mac version:

1. The original CD has both Windows and Mac setup files. Just put it in your Mac and install it. Do not copy the Warcraft III directory from Windows to your Mac, this will not work.
2. If you cannot find your CD, but you still have a valid serial you can register your game on http://battle.net . Just create an account and go to "Manage Games". Enter your serial and get the Blizzard Downloader for Warcraft 3 (Mac).

Note: The Blizzard Downloader is basically a Torrent client, so there are some official Torrents for this.